# macvim can not fold code "E490: No fold found"

Tags: vim, macvim

I can not fold my code in macvim

my environment and settings is at the gist link https://gist.github.com/poc7667/7035979

is there any idead ?

```
hi  Comment  ctermfg=6



"function SetCafeOptions()
    "CoffeeCompile
    ":set nonu
    ":res -24
    ":res +24
"endfunction

set encoding=utf-8 
set fileencoding=utf-8 

colorscheme elflord            
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set expandtab  
set shiftwidth=4

"make it autoreload
set autoread 

"auto move it last time the position you viewed
"make vim save and load the folding of the document each time it loads"
""also places the cursor in the last place that it was left."

"try to set show ansi color
if &term=="ansi" 
    set t_Co=0 
endif

"set expandtab

filetype on

if has("cscope")
    set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
    set csto=0
    set cst
    set nocsverb
    " add any database in current directory
    if filereadable("cscope.out")
        cs add cscope.out
        " else add database pointed to by environment
    elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
        cs add $CSCOPE_DB
    endif
    set csverb
    set cscopetag
    set cscopequickfix=s-,g-,c-,d-,t-,e-,f-,i-
endif

"let Tlist can close windows at one time
let Tlist_Show_One_File=1
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow=1

" Key map
" Presee F4 and you can open the NERDTree
nnoremap <silent> <F4> :NERDTree<CR>  
"nnoremap <silent> <F3> :!/usr/bin/env python %<CR>
" Show function List with Tlist 
nnoremap <F12> :TlistToggle<CR>

" Map ctrl+q to ctrlw+ctrlw
"
"nnoremap <silent> <C-q>  :<C-w><C-w>

"switch in splitted window
map <c-d> <c-w>l
map <c-a> <c-w>h

"set highlight
set hlsearch

"set autocomplet 
"autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html.erb set filetype=html.eruby
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html.erb set filetype=erb.html.eruby
filetype plugin on

"auto import python template
autocmd bufnewfile *.py 0r ~/common_lib/python/tmpl.py


map gn :bn<cr>
map gp :bp<cr>
map ff :CtrlP<cr>
map gt :buffers<cr>
"set NerdTreeSize
let g:NERDTreeWinSize=12
"auto close the nerdtress window whe you open new file
let g:ctrlp_dont_split = 'nerdtree'


set nocompatible " explictly get out of vi-compatible mode

set background=dark " we plan to use a dark background

syntax on " syntax highlighting on

set number " turn on line numbers
set wildignore+=*/test/*,*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip     " MacOSX/Linux

set ruler "always show current position along the bottom

set incsearch " do highlight as you type you search phrase

set ignorecase " case insensitive by default

set smartcase " if there are caps, go case-sensitive


"Rope vim
let $PYTHONPATH .= ":~/install/ropehg/rope:~/install/ropehg/ropemode:~/install/ropehg/ropevim"
source ~/install/ropehg/ropevim/ropevim.vim
let g:pymode_rope_goto_def_newwin = "new"
let ropevim_vim_completion=1
"Use Ctrl + ] . to autocomple
inoremap <C-]> <C-R>=RopeCodeAssistInsertMode()<CR>
map <leader>j :RopeGotoDefinition<CR>
map <leader>r :RopeRename<CR>

" Load the whole plugin
 let g:pymode = 1
" Load run code plugin
 let g:pymode_run = 1

"add ctrlp.vim setting
""
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'tmp$\|\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$\|.rvm$'
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
let g:ctrlp_match_window_bottom=1
let g:ctrlp_max_height=15
let g:ctrlp_match_window_reversed=0
let g:ctrlp_mruf_max=500
let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks=1


"Vundle
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
 call vundle#rc()
 Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
 Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
 Bundle 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
"coffee script"
 Bundle 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
 Bundle 'ack.vim'
 Bundle 'matchit.zip'
 "Markdown"
 "Bundle 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
 ""Vim-scripts repo
 Bundle 'The-NERD-Commenter'
 Bundle 'pep8'
 ""Bundle 'AutoClose'
 filetype plugin indent on

 nmap <leader>a <Esc>:Ack ""

 "folding code
 nnoremap <space> za
 vnoremap <space> zf

" pep8
let g:pep8_map='<leader>8'

"coffee script"
call pathogen#infect()


"make vim save and load the folding of the document each time it loads"
""also places the cursor in the last place that it was left."
au BufWinLeave *.* mkview
au BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview

let Tlist_Use_Right_Window   = 1

"autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == "" | setlocal ft=python | endif

"markdown https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/wiki"
"let g:vim_markdown_folding_disabled=1

"auto exec ruby and coffee script with F5 , remeber to save file before launching
autocmd FileType python map <leader>p :!python %<cr>
autocmd FileType ruby,rb map <leader>5 :w!<cr>:!ruby %<cr>
autocmd FileType * map <leader>e :qa!<cr>
"autocmd FileType coffee nmap <F5> :CoffeeCompile<cr>
"autocmd FileType coffee map <F5> :call SetCafeOptions()<cr>

so ~/.vim/snippets/support_functions.vim
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your .vimrc doesn't actually enable folding anywhere. Folding is not enabled by default. You need to tell Vim what method to use to fold your code.

What method you use might depend on what type of code you are editing. SOME syntax highlighting files define syntax-based folding. Other syntax files do not. If your code is of a type that supports syntax-based folding, then you can `:setlocal foldmethod=syntax` after loading the file. You can do this in an autocmd in your .vimrc if you like, for example `autocmd FileType c setlocal foldmethod=syntax` or you can do it manually.

Other automatic fold methods include "marker", "expr", and "indent". By default the fold method is "manual" and you must first create folds with `zf` in order to use folding commands.

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: :setlocal foldmethod=syntax works well, but i found adding autocmd FileType c setlocal foldmethod=syntax didn't work. still investigating cause.

Comment: It looks like you've configured your plugins with Vundle incorrectly. There should be a `call vundle#end()` before you turn filetype detection on. Additionally, you have turned filetype detection on at least three times. It must be *off* until after the Vundle instructions. Finally...why do you have both Pathogen *and* Vundle?

Comment: hi, where are you getting your info? :)  did you check my github account? that is old, old, old.  in answer to the above, i had pathogen from way back when, and then installed vundle. will check what you say though. believe locally it is working now, but confusingly i get "E350 Cannot create fold with current 'foldmethod'" when i try "zf" to create a fold. the zc and zo commands etc do open and close a fold correctly. thanks for any insights.

Comment: Well yeah..."create a fold" is only for manual fold method. And marker fold method, which inserts text into your buffer to create the folds. Syntax and expression folding is fully defined by the script that defines the folds, you can't create folds manually. And I got the information in my comment from reading the question text.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the detailed help Ben. much appreciated. really like vim / macvim but tend to do more time in Jetbrains IDEs with their emulator these days (ideavim) sticking to mainstream 101 commands. yeah, i keep dotfiles, and vim-js github repos for some of my configurations and some of it is stale atm. anyhow, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Removing these lines solve the folding problem for me:

```
au BufWinLeave *.* mkview
au BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. By removing those commands, I solved the problem. But, still I dont know why, Could you explain why the problem solved by removing those commands?